# scrapy sql or sqlite ... can't get required output

Tags: sql, sqlite, scrapy

i'm trying to extract input fields from  a website page and the page url (which contain these inputs ) and store them into a database ... ok
`*** code works fine with no errors , but this isn't the desired output i want`

***spider code :***

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'isa_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['testaspnet.vulnweb.com']
    start_urls = ['http://testaspnet.vulnweb.com']

    rules = (
                Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/*' ) ),callback='parse_item'),)

    def parse_item(self, response):

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item=IsaItem()
        item['response_fld']=response.url

        res = hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'text' )]/@id ").extract()
        item['text_input'] = res[0] if res else None # None is default value in case no field found

        res = hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'password')]/@id").extract()
        item['pass_input'] = res[0] if res else None # None is default value in case no field found

        res = hxs.select("//input[(@id or @name) and (@type = 'file')]/@id").extract()
        item['file_input'] = res[0] if res else None # None is default value in case no field found

        return item
```

***pipeline code***

```
    class SQLiteStorePipeline(object):


        def __init__(self):
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect('./project.db')
            self.cur = self.conn.cursor()


        def process_item(self, item, spider):

            self.cur.execute("insert into inputs ( input_name) values(?)", (item['text_input'],))
            self.cur.execute("insert into inputs ( input_name) values(?)", (item['pass_input'],))
            self.cur.execute("insert into inputs ( input_name) values(?)", (item['file_input'],))
            self.cur.execute("insert into links (link) values(?)", (item['response_fld'],))
            self.conn.commit()
            return item
```

**database schema** [picture](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1OX046CZ7L2CrlukLLw-YLObFGeE0Yk_r9t81eTSv1LI/edit)

**required output**  [picture](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1SN3AtAHrk8ShLiiPM76q1Km2ZrgTZM7m2vz3A5jtTGM/edit)
 (sorry for not inserting images directly since my reputation is less than 10)

Comment: @warwaruk `current results ` [picture](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/10ewTKAE1ryuf0-aGqysQMp2E2BkQZBi9YpxhWkaHyaA/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested this:

```
class SQLiteStorePipeline(object):


    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('./project.db')
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()


    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        cursor = self.cur

        target_id = ? # determine target id
        cursor.execute("insert into links (target, link) values(?, ?)", (target_id, item['response_fld'],))
        link_id = cursor.lastrowid # find out just inserted link id

        cursor.execute("insert into inputs (link_id, input_name, input_type) values(?, ?, ?)", (link_id, item['text_input'], 1))
        cursor.execute("insert into inputs (link_id, input_name, input_type) values(?, ?, ?)", (link_id, item['pass_input'], 2))
        cursor.execute("insert into inputs (link_id, input_name, input_type) values(?, ?, ?)", (link_id, item['file_input'], 3))

        self.conn.commit()
```

Comment: thanks a lot , i'm so Sorry for being late in a reply and this is beyond me since some tasks was due .i will check your suggestions today... thanks